# How to build a webscraping function for subreddit?

Tags: python, function, web-scraping

Summary: I want to web scrape subreddit and then turn data into data-frames. I know how to do them individually. But I am stuck with using a function.
Here is how I do it one by one.

```
url = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission'

params3 = {'subreddit':'Apple', 'size': 500,'before':1579411194}
res3 = requests.get(url, params3)
data = res3.json()
post3 = data['data']
apdf3 = pd.DataFrame(post3)
```

Here is the function I came up with so far:

```
url = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission'
def webscrape (subreddit, size,):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        params = {"subreddit":subreddit, 'size':size, 'before': f'post{i}'[-1]['created_utc']}
        res = requests.get(url, params)
        f'data{i}' = res.json()
        f'post{i}' = data[f'data{i}']
        f'ap_df{i}' = pd.DataFrame(f'post{i})
```

My problem is that my first parameter doesn't need 'before'. But after the 'post' is created I need to use 'before' in order for me to get all the posts that are earlier than the last post from the previous action. How do I reconcile this conflict?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is doable, but I don't think f-strings will work here. The code below attaches each dataframe to a dictionary of dataframes. Try it and see if it works:

```
d = {}
url = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission'
def webscraper (subreddit, size,):
    bef = 0 
    for i in range(1, 11):
        if i==1:
            params = {"subreddit":subreddit, 'size':size}
        else:
            params = {"subreddit":subreddit, 'size':size, 'before': bef}
        res = requests.get(url, params)    
        data = res.json()  
        dat = data['data']
        bef = dat[-1]['created_utc']
        df_name = subreddit+str(i)
        d[df_name] = pd.DataFrame(dat)
```

Comment: oh my goodness. that 'if i==1: and else' is genius. I am new to coding. Through your answer, I learned something new! Thank you so much!